# React Application not updating this.state properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, web-frontend

I'm currently heavily working on getting my full-stack and decided to expand my knowledge about JavaScript. This decision eventually took me to React, but I'm - as mentioned - a noob in this library. But that only means that I have to work more with this technology in order to progress in terms of said knowledge.

The actuall issues I'm dealing with seems to be very simple at first sight; Apparently my react app doesn't update this.state properly. I'm aware of the fact, that the method setState in React is asynchronous, so I trigger fellow custom methods when the built in second callback of setState() is fired. This technique apparently isn't the best one, since it's not working as planned at all.

My app is about a simple calculator with the basic math operators. I want to implement a feature, that tracks potential Results of given expressions in real time under the "input", but my approach doesn't work although I think that it is not too far away from a real solution. The right function is triggered at the right time, but both this.state.result and this.state.resultExpression apparently aren't, because they don't show up in their rendered boxes. My updateDigit() function is working as planned, but when it comes to showing the result after hitting the "is equal to"-button, literally nothing shows up - even the whole typed input is gone.

Here is my Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './calc.css';

const showHistory = false;
const decimalPlace = 3;

const operatorSet = ["+", "-", '*', '/', '%'];

class Calculator extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.recentResult == false;
        this.state = {
            output: '0',
            preview: '',
            history: [],
            result: '',
            resultExpression: ''
        };
        this.updateDigit = this.updateDigit.bind(this);
        this.updatePreview = this.updatePreview.bind(this);
        this.clearOutput = this.clearOutput.bind(this);
        this.getResult = this.getResult.bind(this);
        this.showResult = this.showResult.bind(this);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="calculator">
                <div className="comp5">
                    <div className="output">{this.state.output}</div>
                    <div className="preview">{this.state.getResult}</div>
                </div>
                <div className="comp4">
                    <div className="topbtn"><a href="#" draggable="false" onClick={this.updateDigit}>(</a></div>
                    <div className="topbtn"><a href="#" draggable="false" onClick={this.updateDigit}>)</a></div>
                    <div className="topbtn"><a href="#" draggable="false" onClick={this.updateDigit}>%</a></div>
                    <div className="button_div button_control">
                        <a href="#" draggable="false" onClick={this.updateDigit}>/</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="comp3">
                    <div className="numpad"><a href="#" draggable="false" onClick={this.updateDigit}>7</a></div>
                    <div className="numpad"><a href="#" draggable="false" onClick={this.updateDigit}>8</a></div>
                    <div className="numpad npl"><a href="#" draggable="false" onClick={this.updateDigit}>9</a></div>
                    <div className="button_min button_control">
                        <a href="#" draggable="false" onClick={this.updateDigit}>*</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="comp2">
                    <div className="numpad"><a href="#" draggable="false" onClick={this.updateDigit}>4</a></div>
                    <div className="numpad"><a href="#" draggable="false" onClick={this.updateDigit}>5</a></div>
                    <div className="numpad npl"><a href="#" draggable="false" onClick={this.updateDigit}>6</a></div>
                    <div className="button_plus button_control">
                        <a href="#" draggable="false" onClick={this.updateDigit}>-</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="comp1">
                    <div className="numpad"><a href="#" draggable="false" onClick={this.updateDigit}>1</a></div>
                    <div className="numpad"><a href="#" draggable="false" onClick={this.updateDigit}>2</a></div>
                    <div className="numpad npl"><a href="#" draggable="false" onClick={this.updateDigit}>3</a></div>
                    <div className="button_plus button_control">
                        <a href="#" draggable="false" onClick={this.updateDigit}>+</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="comp0">
                    <div className="numpad clear"><a href="#" draggable="false" onClick={this.clearOutput}>C</a></div>
                    <div className="numpad"><a href="#" draggable="false" onClick={this.updateDigit}>0</a></div>
                    <div className="numpad npl"><a href="#" draggable="false" onClick={this.updateDigit}>.</a></div>
                    <div className="button_res button_control">
                        <a href="#" draggable="false" onClick={this.showResult}>=</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <History expressions={this.state.history} />
            </div>
        );
    }


    updateDigit(event) {
        event.preventDefault;
        if (this.recentResult == true || this.state.output == "0") {
            this.recentResult = false;
            this.setState({ output: '' });
        }
        const newDigit = {
            digit: event.target.innerHTML,
            id: Date.now()
        };
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            output: prevState.output.concat(newDigit.digit)
        }), this.updatePreview());
    }


    updatePreview(event) {
        if (this.state.output == "0") {
            this.setState({ preview: '' });
        }
        let checkPreviewable = (output) => {
            var charactersAfterOperator = false;
            for (var i = 0; i < operatorSet.length; i++) {
                var currentOperator = operatorSet[i];
                let operatorLocation = output.indexOf(currentOperator)
                if (operatorLocation < output.length && operatorLocation > 0) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        };
        let previewable = checkPreviewable(this.state.output);
        if (previewable === true) {
            let resultExpression = this.state.resultExpression;
            this.setState({ preview: this.state.result });
        } else {
            this.setState({ preview: '' });
        }
    }


    clearOutput(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({ output: '0' });
    }


    getResult(event) {
        var result = eval(this.state.output).toFixed(decimalPlace);
        var resultExpression = this.state.output + "=" + result;

        this.setState({
            result: result,
            resultExpression: resultExpression
        }, this.updatePreview());
    }


    showResult(event) {
        this.getResult();
        let result = this.state.result;
        let resultExpression = this.state.resultExpression;
        this.setState({ output: result });
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            history: prevState.history.concat(resultExpression)
        }));
        this.recentResult = true;
    }

}

export default Calculator;



class History extends React.Component {
    render() {
        if (showHistory === false) return false;
        return (
            <ul>
                {this.props.expressions.map(expression => (
                    <li>{expression}</li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        )
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea why this is happening, have you actually experienced a similar situation or could you even provide an alternative/solution?

Thank you in advance for every kind of help, J0nny

Answer (score 0):

I was watchig for your code and I can see that you have a lot of setState functions.

Every time you call setstate your component is rendered again, and your code not complete your current flow.

If you need execute anything after setstate function, do you need set a next function as a callback of a setstate function, for example:

`this.setState({value:1}, callBack)`

I hope this help
If you want we can talk in appear or ther thing and I can explain better to you.

Comment: Nah, it doesn't work at all to render any result. Does it work in your setup?

Comment: Sorry @J0nny I fix my answer, You will need make some changes in your code, if you want we can talk by appear or other voice chat, to explain better.

If you dont understood my new answer let me know, I will try help you.

Comment: I didn't know that everything is rendered again after calling setState() ... thank you for this detail. Do you know, how I can manage to call subsequent setState() methods for my code then?

Comment: @J0nny if do you need execute some code after `this.setState` function, you need pass another function as callback, for example: `this.setState({value:1}, callBack)`

But in your currenct cenario I think that you need make some changes in your code, try to reduce the quantity of this.setstate call.

Comment: I did understand what you were saying, but where is the logic in nesting the setState calls in individual methods and calling them separately? The components are apparently rendered again anyways... What do you mean by "reduce the quantity of this.setstate"? Could you get more explicit about your concerns and how to realize them, please? Thank you for the quick responses!

Comment: @J0nny Sorry man, I will try be a little more specific, I will try create some git.gist with a peace of code.

If you want we can do a pair programming, what do you think about?

Comment: Thank you for the offer, but I am currently not interested in any kind of pari programming or voice chat. I was hoping you could provide solutions in this form of comments or answers. Sorry for the late response ... busy day

Comment: I would be happy to see you helping me again @NicolasTakashi

Comment: Sorry for delay @J0nny I will try create something today, my week was complicated.